# Can't upload files with Jquery correctly

Tags: jquery

I found a code in Jquery that help for uploading files, in this link : http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/ , that works perfectly in the Demo but in Localhost any file is uploaded instantly Also it doesn't work with SHP files because I can't found the "file.shp" after a successfull upload in 'uploads' directory. Thanks for advance

Comment: Most likely because your bandwith to localhost is way higher than to the server where that demo is located. So every upload takes only milliseconds on your localhost.

Comment: I doubted about this, so thank you very much :) still have problem with SHP files :/